# How to convert JSON to INI-Format

Tags: json, ini

i would like to know, if there is a way with javascript or typescript to
convert JSON to INI-Format. Im New­bie.

from:

```
{
"peerEndpoint": "blub.bla:49997",
"peerPublicKey": "dfasdfasfsdfasdfa",
"deviceIPs": [
  "10.40.16.1"
],
"peerAllowedIPs": [
  "10.40.16.0/22",
  "10.40.0.0/20"
],
"applications": {}
}
```

to:

```
Address = 10.40.16.1/32
[Peer]
PublicKey = dfasdfasfsdfasdfa
Endpoint = blub.bla:49997
AllowedIPs = 10.40.16.0/22, 10.40.0.0/20
```

thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. See below:

```js
/*
Address = 10.40.16.1/32
[Peer]
PublicKey = dfasdfasfsdfasdfa
Endpoint = blub.bla:49997
AllowedIPs = 10.40.16.0/22, 10.40.0.0/20
*/
let json = {
"peerEndpoint": "blub.bla:49997",
"peerPublicKey": "dfasdfasfsdfasdfa",
"deviceIPs": [
  "10.40.16.1"
],
"peerAllowedIPs": [
  "10.40.16.0/22",
  "10.40.0.0/20"
],
"applications": {}
}

function displayIPs(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => item + ((item.indexOf("/") === -1) ? "/32" : "")).join(",");
}

let template = `Address = ${displayIPs(json.deviceIPs)}<br>[Peer]<br>`;
let jsonKeys = ['peerEndpoint', 'peerPublicKey', 'peerAllowedIPs'];
for (let key of jsonKeys) {
    if (key.indexOf("peer") === 0) {
        let k = key.substring(4);
        template += `${k} = ${(k === "AllowedIP") ? displayIPs(json[key]) : json[key]}<br>`;
    }
}

document.write(template);
```

Explanation:

- we create a json
- we define a function that takes an IP address and defaults its end to /32 if there is no port defined
- we create a template, using template literals, using this helper function to cope with the address
- we create a set of peer keys to ensure the order of our items
- we loop this set
- and for each item, we handle its values as IP addresses if needed and add them as they are otherwise

Answer (score 1):

in case you use by any chance a node.js environment:
Than you could just install and use

```
npm install json2ini
```

and in your code you could use something like this:

```
const json2ini = require('json2ini');

const jsonData = {
  // YOUR JSON-DATA 
};

const iniData = json2ini(jsonData);
console.log(iniData);
```

If not I guess the approach from Lajos Arpad will do the trick.

Comment: sadly it doesnt work  `npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json2ini - Not found 
npm ERR! 404  'json2ini@*' is not in this registry.`